# What is the font in the BSN logo?

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know what font is used in BSN protein powder logo?

[image]

[Source](http://www.gobsn.com/)

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Please reference [our font section](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions) in regards to asking a font question because at this time your question shows no effort or where you have tried to look and that tends to receive downvotes.  Please edit your question with the sites you have already looked.

Answer (score 2):

That is Bauhaus 93 (an older version), this version has a more condensed 's' and a flat capital 'b'. This version of the famous font is made by Microsoft to be featured in Word.

But when redirected from the [site of Microsoft](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-bauhaus#product_top) a newer version is found.

[image]

Comment: Bauhaus is not the correct font, unless it is highly modified.  Notice that the capital B in the logo is flat across the top, whereas in Bauhaus, the cap-B's bowl wraps all the way around to the meanline.  The cap-N's are pretty similar, but the cap-S's are very different:  Bauhaus is wide, angular, and rotationally symmetric, whereas the logo S is narrow and much more curved, not to mention not symmetric.